# Нужно отсортировать товары в нужном количестве laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день у меня вопрос. Допустим есть 100 товаров некоторые из них с вип статусом мне нужно отсортировать по вип статусу что-б было с начало 4 товара с вип статусом потом 10 обычных потом заново 4 с вип статусом и так далее. Как это можно сделать в laravel

Comment: думайте как это сделать  на SQL  и не в ларавел. Когда придумаете как сделать в БД перенесете в ORM. Либо сортируйте уже после получения данных. но и тут не о ларевел думать надо а о пхп в целом. Подозреваю, что нумерация и деление нацело на 4 и 10 вам помогут в решении задачи.

Comment: Долго думал над твоим предложением, и не смог придумать решение(

Comment: так приложите код, как вы пытались решить вопрос то. версию СУБД тоже укажите. А лучше так: если решаете на уровне БД - то приложите исходный пример данных и запрос. Если на пхп, то  пример данных массива и как решали.

Comment: Структура данных https://prnt.sc/kxYICSQrf-lV запроса так такого ещё нету пробовал использовать примеры запросов с вот этой статьи http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_integer_division.html чёт не выходить думаю я копаю не в том направление

Comment: Что за сортировка такая, по какому принципу?

Comment: По vip_status Нужно что-б первые 4 товара выводились с вип статусом потом 10 обычные потом 4 с вип статусом и ТД